# Hide and show of a div on click of a button

Tags: sql-server, database, web-hosting

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button style="width:80%;height:35px;">Toggle between hiding and showing the      paragraphs</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this code hide and show the div on the click of a button.
this code is working fine ...but i want that div should be hidden first. it will shown after clicking.

Comment: why you have tagged sql-server, database, web-hosting

Comment: add style="display: none;" to the tag that should be initially hidden

Comment: olk .. thanxx alot...

Answer (score 1):

Add style display:none in p tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
        });
     });
 </script>
 <style>
        p{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

     <button style="width:80%;height:35px;">Toggle between hiding and showing the paragraphs</button>

    <p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    <p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
</body>
```